# How to apply list of rotations to multiple bones using animation nodes

Tags: animation, armature, animation-nodes

Currently I am  using Expression node to apply rotation to a single bone, is there a way to apply a list of rotations to multiple bones using a single Expression node? I have tried everything, but this expression doesn't accept lists

The order of rotations and the bones is the same.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it is not encouraged, you can technically use list comprehensions as follows. A list comprehension takes the form:

```
[element.attribute for element in elements]
```

`element.attribute` has to be an actual object, thus writing an assignment operator instead like `bone.rotation_quaternion = quat` won't work, because assignment operators won't return anything. However, if you used the `setattr()` function, it will execute and return `None`. In conclusion, you can write the expression as follows:

```
[setattr(bone, "rotation_quaternion", quaternion) for bone, quaternion in zip(object.pose.bones, quaternions)]
```

[image: Node Tree]

If you want to assign the quaternion only to the bones at the indices defined by an integer list, you would use an expression as follows:

```
[setattr(object.pose.bones[i], "rotation_quaternion", quaternions[i]) for i in indices]
```

Instead of looping over the bones and quaternions themselves, you loop over the indices and get the bones and quaternions at the current index.

[image: Node Tree]

If you quaternion list is masked based on the indices, then you should loop over the quaternions directly as follows:

```
[setattr(object.pose.bones[i], "rotation_quaternion", quaternion) for i, quaternion in zip(indices, quaternions)]
```

[image: Node Tree]

Comment: Thank you Omar, bone can be an index or bone name lists, right?

Comment: @Denis No, `bone` is an object (Python object). Your inputs to the expression node should be 1. `object`: Your armature. 2. `quaternions`: Your quaternion list.

Comment: That works perfect, but how would I modify the expression if I want to filter the bones?

Comment: @Denis What do you mean by "filter the bones"? You want to apply the assignment to only a number of specific of bones? What should define whether a bone should have an assignment or not? Based on its name? A boolean list? A list of indices?

Comment: I apply the rotation to specific bones and use a list of indices, for example: [2,3,4,7,8,9]

Comment: @Denis Edited the answer.

Comment: What I mean is that the list of rotations should apply to the filtered bones.

Comment: @Denis Edited the answer, check the documentation for the [expression node](https://animation-nodes-manual.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/subprograms/expression.html). There are some information about list comprehensions.

Comment: Thank you, thats what I needed, I will check the documentation.